# Executing a code in Rstudio with a table in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, r, loops

I have a code that I run in Rstudio that takes long to process and I 
want to be able to run the same code in R when dfnew1 is in sql server 2012. Is this feasible? Below is a part of the code, I just want to understand how to tweak it so it calls and update a sql server table. is there a wrapper I can put around the code?

```
for(i in 2:nrowdf){
  dfnew1[i,5] <- dfnew1[i,4] *  dfnew1[i-1,5]
}
```

Comment: That takes a long time to process because it's really inefficient. There are better ways to do that in R as well as in SQL, so I would suggest not using that code at all.

Comment: What other approach are you suggesting?

Comment: Before discussing how to improve your code, you need to make a reproducible example.

Comment: How about `dfnew1[-1, 5] = cumprod(dfnew1[-1, 4]) * dfnew1[1, 5]` (for R, you can search for cumulative product in SQL)

Comment: Thanks Gregor , I will check it out!

Comment: I am still trying to understand if it is feasible to manipulate a SQLServer table inside R.

Comment: I don't know anything about the new R integration with SQL Server, but that aside you have two options: (a) SQL does the operations or (b) R does the operations. In case (a) you can use RODBC or the like to send SQL code from R to the the database, or you can use dplyr with a database connection that is able to translate some R code to to SQL and and send it over for you. There is a `dplyr` vignette on the topic (though they are focused on open source SQL flavors, you will need extra packages for it to work with SQL Serfer).

Comment: In case (b), you would import the table from SQL to R, execute arbitrary code, and then send it back - using RODBC or the like. You should see the documentation of whatever package you are using to connect to SQL to see how to update a table. These methods are not "smart". If you are only changing the 5th column, you would do well to specifically update the fifth column, otherwise it will rewrite the whole table.